# Microsoft Crm 4.0 On Premise to Microsoft Crm 2011 On Demand Migration

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am moving a system from Microsoft Crm 4.0 On Premise to Microsoft Crm 2011 On Demand (hosted).  What is the best way to migrate all of the data?  Is there a data mapping built in for that or any tool recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

There is no dedicated tool for migrating an on premise organization to Dynamics CRM Online.

The first step of such a migration would be an upgrade of your local system to Dynamics CRM 2011. This ensures that you are on the same customization level.

For the migration itself, you could use for example [Scribe](http://www.scribesoft.com/) or you could script it by yourself. This should be rather "easy" as you only have to transfer the data. The data structure itself, remains the same.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of Scribe.  We've used that tool for multiple migrations and it greatly expedites the process.  Be aware though - mass data migration through the CRM is no fast process.  Depending upon your record counts you could be looking at days to load the new system.

Answer (score 0):

We've just completed the development of a tool which automatically manages the transfer of data from a CRM 2011 On Premise database to CRM Online.  We're in the process of making this available publicly, in the mean time if you're interested then please contact info@synchronicity-systems.com

UPDATE: Our software is now available for download, for more information check out the website here http://www.synchronicity-systems.co.uk/echo/